# What is the advantage of adding namespace in web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, namespaces, web-config

What is the advantage of adding namespace in `web.config` file?

```
<configuration>
     <system.web>
              <pages>
                <namespaces>
                  <add namespace="System.Collections" />
                </namespaces>
              </pages>
          </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

This will allow to add the namespaces of the items you commonly use in your views so you don't need to add the references in each page / view when you need to use them.

Comment: Does it affect only Web Site Project, and doesn't Web Application Project?

Comment: Is this namespace automatically called in c# code file also? If we have add namespace in web.config there has no need to add those namespace in code file by using the `using` command (like :- `using System.Collections`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces you define here are automatically imported into all pages of an application.